# *** Stack smasing detected *** // Trying to print a char

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio_ext.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() 
{
  char a[10],c[10];
  int i,b;

  b=1;
  i=0;

  printf(": ");
  scanf("%s",a);
  fflush(stdin);
  __fpurge(stdout);

  while(i<=10)
  {

    c[i]=a[i]+b;
    i++;

  }
  printf("%s",c);
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

So the thing is I want to print a char with the next character in the *ASCII table*, but every time I run it I get this error, although it seems to work with a size of 10:

```
: asdf
*** stack smashing detected ***: /home/polo/Escritorio/ejemplo/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/ejemplo terminated
bteg� c8�l�#w�@���
RUN FINISHED; Aborted; core dumped; real time: 4s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is UB.

Comment: WTF is `__fpurge`?

Answer (score 3):

By saying

```
 while(i<=10)
```

you're [off-by one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). It should be

```
 while( i < 10 )
```

as C arrays use 0-based indexing.

That said, as per `C11`, chapter 7.21.5.2

> If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
>   operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream
>   to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

So, don't do `fflush(stdin)`, technically, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Finally, `scanf("%s",a);` opens up the *potential* for buffer overflow. Limit the input buffer length like

```
 scanf("%9s",a); //when a is an array of size 10
```